# Как получить полное тело http запроса?

Tags: http, https

Есть программа которая представляет из себя урезанную версию браузера. Я хочу мониторить все содержание запросов которые эта программа отправляет с моей машины. Сорцов у меня нет. Может быть есть какие-то консольные утилиты которые позволят мне мониторить порты, что бы это посмотреть? Или как-то еще.

Если максимально конкретизировать вопрос: как получить максимально полные данные о запросах с моей машины?

Спасибо.

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Network Monitor от Microsoft

Comment: Еще fiddler если программа умеет работать с прокси-сервером. Можно загнать ее в виртуалку без доступа к инету если хочется гарантий что она ничего не отправляет в обход прокси-сервера.